# Filtering in ngRepeat directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have array like following

```
var people = [
            {
                name: "a",
                status: "approved"
            }, {
                name: "b",
                status: "pending"
            }, {
                name: "c",
                status: "approved"
            }, {
                name: "d",
                status: "pending"
            },

        ];
```

In ng-repeat, is there any way to filter and show the object where status is "approved"?

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="p in people | filter:p.status='approved'">
      {{p}}
    </div>`

use angularjs filter

Comment: @guru: Shouldn't it be `<div ng-repeat="p in people | filter:{status:'approved'}">` ?

Comment: I guess both do the same thing 
http://plnkr.co/edit/6oDpLJphqViau0X8PfXw?p=preview

Comment: That's interesting :) Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer taken from comment made by @guru

```
<div ng-repeat="p in people | filter:p.status='approved'">{{p}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<label ng-repeat="pep in people">
  <label ng-show="pep.status == 'approved'">{{pep.name}}</label>
</label>
```